# error: cannot find symbol for CompatibilityAssertions

Tags: java

Am trying to build project, but receives next error. Can't deal why. Seems like it written without spell errors.

*D:\Projects\iqpdct\iqpdct-domain\src\test\java\de\iq2dev\domain\datatype\OctetSt
ringDatatypeTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import org.assertj.core.api.CompatibilityAssertions;*

Comment: find jar file (with a google search)  and add that to your project

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a jar on your Java buildpath. According to the thrown exception you should be able to find the jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core). The link points to a Maven repository of assertj-core. After opening the link please select the proper version of aspectj for your project.

Comment: I am using gradle, and in "dependecies" section I have "testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.+'"
Should it be automatically downloaded, or not?

Sorry, for my noob's questions

Comment: If you are using gradle and the jar is specified in the dependencies section it should be downloaded automatically. To have this happen, you should also have something like mavenCentral() in the repositories section.